# UINavigation Controller before Tab Bar Controller

Tags: controller, navigation, tabbar

I want to have a navigation controller enrollment flow before my actual tab bar controller flow starts up. Right now I've created two different apps with two delegates.

I thought it might be possible to load my enrollment navcontroller xib flow first, then upon enrollment completion close it and load the tab bar controller.

I'm thinking this would be done in a single app delegate, but can't quite come up with the code to call navigation controller flow first and when finished a button clicked would load the tabbar flow/xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't too hard, just a few simple things to understand.

First if you are creating a TabBar Controller, the TabBar Controller will always have to be the root view. Once you know this the next step is to see what view or xib the TabBar controller calls first.

Once you know this go to the view or xib's view controller code. In that code create function

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
}
```

Within the above function you can inject the navigation view, but first you must tell the navigation view what the first view you want to be displayed, done like this:

```
PersonalInfoVC *personalInfoVC = [[PersonalInfoVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"PersonalInfoVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController  = [[UINavigationController alloc]  
                                           initWithRootViewController:personalInfoVC];
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

then in each view to call the next view use code like this:

```
DepositDetailsVC *depositDetailsVC = [[DepositDetailsVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"DepositDetailsVC" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:depositDetailsVC animated:YES];
```

Finally when you are done with the flow of the injected navigation controller run this code to go back to your original TabBar controller

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Easy enough. :)